# Variation selectors are not recognized as Japanese text

Tags: feature-request, kanji

#### Problem

The desktop site seems to feature a smart detection of Japanese text span to change the font. However, it fails to recognize [variation sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_form_(Unicode)) as continuous Japanese text.

> 葛城市

For example the quotation above contains four codepoints: [U+845B, U+E0100, U+57CE, U+5E02] and should display the first character in specific form

> ## {{ja:葛}}

instead of

> ## {{ja:葛}}

However, the actual rendering separates the chunk before and after the variation selector U+E0100, which makes the sequence invalid.

[image][image]

I was able to work around it using the language tag feature of furigana engine `{{​ja:字}}` to group the base character and selector together (as above), but it is not very friendly to Markdown notations (see [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86142/7810)) and looks obviously bad in the mobile app.

#### Suggestion

Treat variation selectors (U+FE00—U+FE0D*, U+E0100—U+E01EF) following a Japanese character as a part of Japanese text as well.

* <sup>U+FE0E, U+FE0F are practically restricted to emoji usage.</sup>